# Unknown SQL Issue with INSERT sentence

Tags: java, sql

Basically I'm trying to update a Database table with the values of a getSelectRow. As you can see, the query finds the correct data, but has huge issues when actually trying to add it to the database.
The error is in the SQL syntax, but I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please Help.

This is the query that it executes, but I have no idea why it isn't updating the table.

```
INSERT INTO customerdetails 
      FName        = 'Tim'
  AND SName        = 'Cooley'
  AND Address      = '52     Buckminster Drive Dorridge Solihull West Mids'
  AND Postcode     = 'B93 8PG'
```

Java code:

```
private void sendBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int insertRow = newOrderTbl.getSelectedRow();
    int col2 = 0;

    String sql3 = "INSERT INTO customerdetails VALUES "
            + "FName            = '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2)     +"'"
            + "AND SName        = '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+1)   +"'"
            + "AND Address      = '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+2)   +"'"
            + "AND Postcode     = '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+3)   +"'";
    System.out.println(sql3); 
    try{

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
        pst.executeUpdate(sql3);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");   


        CustomerTable();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }


}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I know it does, but it doesn't matter as this is a personal project that will never get published anywhere.
The error is what I need help with please.

Comment: What is the returnvalue of `pst.executeUpdate(...)`? According to the Javadoc, it returns "either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing".

Comment: @TimCooley I guess you never tried out my answer =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, your SQL syntax is wrong (at least that it is a non-standard SQL syntax for your database engine). Second, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

In order to solve both problems, you should use a `PreparedStatement` (that you're doing in the wrong way). A basic example from your code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO customerdetails (FName, SName, Address, Postcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatemtnt(sql);
pst.setString(1, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2));
pst.setString(2, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+1));
pst.setString(3, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+2));
pst.setString(4, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+3));
pst.executeUpdate();
//rest of code...
```

Assuming your SQL syntax will work, then you should pass the values as parameters, similar to the previous example:

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO customerdetails VALUES "
        + "FName            = ?"
        + "AND SName        = ?"
        + "AND Address      = ?"
        + "AND Postcode     = ?"
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
pst.setString(1, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2));
pst.setString(2, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+1));
pst.setString(3, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+2));
pst.setString(4, newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+3));
pst.executeUpdate();
//rest of code...
```

Answer (score 0):

for update statement it will be -

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO customerdetails(FName,SName,Address,Postcode) VALUES "
            + " '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2)     +"',"
            + " '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+1)   +"',"
            + " '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+2)   +"',"
            + " '" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+3) + "')";
```

Also you should use PreparedStatement for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please change it to

```
String sql3 = "INSERT INTO customerdetails(FName,SName,Address,Postcode) VALUES ("
            + "'" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2)     +"'"
            + "'" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+1)   +"'"
            + "'" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+2)   +"'"
            + "'" + newOrderTbl.getValueAt(insertRow, col2+3)   +"')";
```

The generated insert statement in your code seems invalid. Please see [SQL Insert Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for more information

Also, the better approach would be to create a dedicated Serverside DAO class to handle database operations.